# How to convert data from one row to multiple rows base on Date

Tags: sql, oracle

I wish to convert data from  one row to multiple rows base on start_time and end_time.

INPUT DATA:

| ID | Start_Time | End_Time | Down_Mins |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC123 | 11/22/2022 12:01 | 11/29/2022 14:33 | 10232.47 |

I need to write SQL for this requirement:

OUTPUT_DATA:

| ID | Start_Time | End_Time | Down_Mins |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC123 | 11/22/2022 12:01 | 11/23/2022 7:00 | 1138.55 |
| ABC123 | 11/23/2022 7:00 | 11/24/2022 7:00 | 1440 |
| ABC123 | 11/24/2022 7:00 | 11/25/2022 7:00 | 1440 |
| ABC123 | 11/25/2022 7:00 | 11/26/2022 7:00 | 1440 |
| ABC123 | 11/26/2022 7:00 | 11/27/2022 7:00 | 1440 |
| ABC123 | 11/27/2022 7:00 | 11/28/2022 7:00 | 1440 |
| ABC123 | 11/28/2022 7:00 | 11/29/2022 7:00 | 1440 |
| ABC123 | 11/29/2022 7:00 | 11/29/2022 14:33 | 453.92 |

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwdTt.png)

Comment: Please do not spam lots of unnecessary tags. SQL Server and Oracle are two different RDBMS and have different syntaxes. given that your other tags relate to Oracle I've remove SQL Server; if that is incorrect then please [edit] your question and add the correct tags.

Comment: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/2029983)

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (You've already got one product specific answer - hope you're not wasting someone's time writing an answer for "wrong" dbms.)

Comment: Data type for Start_Time and End_Time columns?

Comment: thanks all for your support, sorry for confusing, its oracle db im using.

Comment: I would not do this in SQL - use a programming language to generate rows of data. This is much cleaner and easier to understand than the clever abomination in the answer below!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive query to split the data into rows for each 24-hour period starting at 7am:

```sql
WITH days (id, start_time, day_end, end_time, day_mins, down_mins) AS (
  SELECT id,
         start_time,
         LEAST(TRUNC(start_time - INTERVAL '7' HOUR) + INTERVAL '31' HOUR, end_time),
         end_time,
         LEAST((LEAST(TRUNC(start_time - INTERVAL '7' HOUR) + INTERVAL '31' HOUR, end_time) - start_time) * 24 * 60, down_mins),
         down_mins - LEAST((LEAST(TRUNC(start_time - INTERVAL '7' HOUR) + INTERVAL '31' HOUR, end_time) - start_time) * 24 * 60, down_mins)
  FROM   table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT id,
         day_end,
         LEAST(day_end + INTERVAL '24' HOUR, end_time),
         end_time,
         LEAST((LEAST(day_end + INTERVAL '24' HOUR, end_time) - day_end) * 24 * 60, down_mins),
         down_mins - LEAST((LEAST(day_end + INTERVAL '24' HOUR, end_time) - day_end) * 24 * 60, down_mins)
  FROM   days
  WHERE  day_end < end_time
  AND    down_mins > 0
)
SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY id, start_time SET order_id
SELECT id,
       start_time,
       day_end AS end_time,
       day_mins AS down_mins
FROM   days;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (ID, Start_Time, End_Time, Down_Mins) AS
SELECT 'ABC123',
       DATE '2022-11-23' + INTERVAL '7' HOUR - NUMTODSINTERVAL(1138.55, 'MINUTE'),
       DATE '2022-11-23' + INTERVAL '7' HOUR + NUMTODSINTERVAL(10232.47 - 1138.55, 'MINUTE'),
       10232.47
FROM   DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ID | START_TIME | END_TIME | DOWN_MINS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC123 | 2022-11-22 12:01:27 | 2022-11-23 07:00:00 | 1138.55 |
| ABC123 | 2022-11-23 07:00:00 | 2022-11-24 07:00:00 | 1440 |
| ABC123 | 2022-11-24 07:00:00 | 2022-11-25 07:00:00 | 1440 |
| ABC123 | 2022-11-25 07:00:00 | 2022-11-26 07:00:00 | 1440 |
| ABC123 | 2022-11-26 07:00:00 | 2022-11-27 07:00:00 | 1440 |
| ABC123 | 2022-11-27 07:00:00 | 2022-11-28 07:00:00 | 1440 |
| ABC123 | 2022-11-28 07:00:00 | 2022-11-29 07:00:00 | 1440 |
| ABC123 | 2022-11-29 07:00:00 | 2022-11-29 14:33:55 | 453.916666666666666666666666666666666667 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/PfxodE6V)